# Error with my SFML collision function

Tags: c++, game-physics, sfml

I have been trying to get a small collision function to work that I found on a different site. It works when it comes to the X axis, but not on the y axis.

```
bool getCollision(float firstObjectX, float firstObjectY, float firstObjectWidth, float firstObjectHeight, float secondObjectX, float secondObjectY, float secondObjectWidth, float secondObjectHeight)
{
 if(firstObjectX + firstObjectWidth > secondObjectX && firstObjectX < secondObjectX + secondObjectWidth)
 {
    if(firstObjectY + firstObjectHeight > secondObjectY && firstObjectY < secondObjectY + secondObjectHeight)
    {
        return true;
    }
 }  
 else
 {
    return false;
 }

}
```

With the above code, when I run into the object going left to right it works only when I hit the other item. However when I am going up or down as long as it is in the same Y column it says I have a colision the entire time.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a much simpler method:

```
if (shape1.getGlobalBounds().intersects( shape.getGlobalBounds())){

                    std::cout << "Collision";
                }
```

This worked perfectly for what I was looking to do.